# Why do non-static data member initializers defeat uniform initialization syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization-list

If all of your class/struct data members lack initializers, you can use uniform initialization syntax to construct the object.

```
struct foo
{
    int i;
    float f;
};
...
foo bar{ 5, 3.141f };
```

But if one or more members have initializers, uniform initialization syntax becomes invalid.

```
struct foo
{
    int i;
    float f = 0;
};
...
foo bar{ 5, 3.141f };  // Compiler error.
```

I surmise that the addition of a data member initializer automatically implements one or more default constructors and suppresses the default implementation of the `initialization_list` constructor. Is that the intended standard? Why does it work this way?

Comment: There is no "default implementation of the `initializer_list` constructor". What you have in the first snippet is called *aggregate initialization*.

Comment: To complement @Xeo's comment, see *8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]* and *8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]*.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is intended by the standard.  What you are attempting here is *aggregate initialization*.  Unfortunately, your second `foo` is no longer considered an aggregate due to the equal initializer of `f`.  See *8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]* (emphasis mine):

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), **no brace-or-equalinitializers for non-static data members (9.2)**, no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Because you have an equal initializer for the member `f`, you will need to provide a custom constructor to support the syntax you are after:

```
struct foo
{
  int i;
  float f = 0;
  constexpr foo(int i, float f) : i(i), f(f) { }
};
...
foo bar{ 5, 3.141f }; // now okay
```

As to *why* this was specified in the standard, I have no idea.

Comment: Note that it's under consideration for the next standard to allow aggregate init even with non-static data member initializers.